# Calling a vbscript function on ASP Classic

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

```
<script language=vbscript>
Public Function testfunc(a)
    MsgBox a
End Function
</Script>    
<%
Call testfunc("hi")
%>
```

I simplified the code because I am not sure if this would work at all. I am trying to use vbscript Function to open "Outlook.application". I need this to run client side but the asp part should run server side as it queries SQL with Windows.Authentication(IIS App Identity).

Is this possible at all or am I missing a point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about this logically.  Client side means that the code is executed by the browser after the page loads, server side means that it's executed on the server before the page loads.  The server will ignore your client side code and your browser won't even see your server side code so it won't work

Comment: Thank you very much, I know how to code web, somehow, I have been trying different ways to get this working and forgot this basic principle. Thanks for this closure.